# Why do we need third party build tools?

Tags: build

Why do we need third party build tools like [this](http://www.finalbuilder.com/Products/FinalBuilder/ScreenShots/tabid/62/Default.aspx) one?

Don't we have build facilities integrated into our IDEs?

What do these tools actually do that is not provided in the IDEs?

Comment: I don't get the question.  My copy of Eclipse seems to do a build.  I have a build facility integrated into my IDE.  Which IDE are you using that has no build facility built-in?

Comment: @S.Lott, Follow the link [http://www.finalbuilder.com/Products/FinalBuilder/ScreenShots/tabid/62/Default.aspx]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The ability to run a build server which doesn't have to start an IDE in order to build a product?

The ability to have a *standardized* build so that a developer doesn't have to install another IDE just to be able to build some third party code? Think about the Open Source world - you don't want to force all the developers on a project to use the same IDE, nor do you want to force any user who wants to build from source to install a whole IDE just for the sake of that. It's a lot easier to run Ant than to keep track of a whole bunch of IDEs.

What's *good* is that IDEs such as Eclipse support 3rd party build systems like Ant - that's the way it should work IMO, rather than tailoring the build to one specific IDE.

The .NET world has a slightly different take on this, where MSBuild is part of the framework, but is *also* the build format used by Visual Studio. (Personally I like to use NAnt for control of the build process, and MSBuild to do the actual compilation stage.)

Comment: Which bit, and why? An IDE is for a lot more than building - so if I *only* want to build (on a build server), why would I want to have a full IDE?

Comment: Also, standardizing and automating the build helps alleviate the "works on my box" syndrome, since people have a common reference build!

Answer (score 3):

Adding to Jon's answer concerning the build server - ensuring that the build can be done cleanly on a machine that doesn't have e.g. trial versions of components, and various developer tools, so the end users machine won't need those either.